# Using the conjunction "when" with the Present Perfect, Present Perfect Continuous, Past Simple and the Past Continuous Tense

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, when

From a grammatical point of view, I'm trying to understand the use of these tenses in the "when" clause. I'll give you an example. All of these example sentences are from native English speakers, both AmE and BrE:

> 1. Have you ever visited the Louvre when you **were** in Paris?
> 2. Have you ever seen a yellow butterfly when you **were** looking for a white butterfly?
> 3. Have you ever visited the Louvre when you **have been** in Paris?
>
>    <sup>Source: WordReference.com</sup>
> 4. Senator Kaine: I have heard Hillary Clinton say over and over again, **when I've been sitting** next to her and **when I've
>    watched** her on TV that, with respect to the e-mails, "I made a
>    mistake and I've learned something and I wouldn't do it again.", and
>    I've heard her apologize.
>
>    <sup>Source: COCA/SPOK: MEET THE PRESS 10:30 AM EST. Donald Trump`s Tough Week; Interview with Sen. Tim Kaine</sup>

So, from what I've found out from native English speakers, some of them assert that these sentences are grammatically incorrect, while others assert that they are completely acceptable. We're talking about the repeated past events.

Could someone explain from a grammatical POV, are these sentences correct and, if so, what is the difference between them and how should I use them?

Comment: Americans often prefer simple past rather than past perfect or continous.

Comment: I'd use [1'] Have you ever visited the Louvre when in Paris? or [1"] Did you ever visit the Louvre when you were in Paris? (not [1] or [3]) [2] and [4] sound quite natural; the change from 'when I've been sitting next to her' to 'when I've watched her on TV' conveys the switch from chance to intentional audience. [['audience' M-W sense 4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/audience)]

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth What do you mean by the _change_? He said: _"when I've been sitting next to her **and** when I've watched her on TV"_. I don't see any change.

Comment: Contrast 'When I've sat next to her and when I've been watching her on TV' which is suboptimal imo.

Comment: Honestly any of these are understandable, which is what really matters.

Answer (score 5):

> - Have you ever visited the Louvre when you have been in Paris?
> - Senator Kaine: I have heard Hillary Clinton say over and over again, when I've been sitting next to her and when I've watched her on TV that, with respect to the e-mails, "I made a mistake and I've learned something and I wouldn't do it again.", and I've heard her apologize.

The present perfect is not usual in this context.

[image]

For the question of deciding between the past perfect and the simple past, there exist a clear-cut guide line to be found in PEU (*Practical English Usage*, Michael Swann, second edition), **§ 421, 5**; it indicates that the simple past is more natural in those sentences.

> The past perfect can help to mark the first action as separate, independent of the second, completed before the second. In contrast, the simple past can suggest that the first action 'leads into' the other, or that there is a cause-and-effect link between them. Compare:
>
> - *When I **had opened** the window I sat down and had a cup of tea.*
>   (NOT "*When I **opened** the window I sat down…*")
> - *When I **opened** the windows the cat jumped out.*
>   (More natural than "*When I **had opened** the windows…*")
> - *When I **had written** my letters I did some gardening.*
>   (NOT "*When I **wrote** my letters I did some gardening.*")
>   *When I wrote to her she came at once.*

Because the action of being in Paris leads to the visit (second action) and the action of sitting next to her and the action of watching her on TV lead into the action of hearing Hilary Clinton say something, the singled out sentences above should be rewritten as follows.

> - Have you ever visited the Louvre when you **were** in Paris?
> - Senator Kaine: I have heard Hillary Clinton say over and over again, when I **was** sitting next to her and when I **watched** her on TV that, with respect to the e-mails, "I made a mistake and I've learned something and I wouldn't do it again.", and I've heard her apologize.

Comment: Past perfect is one of the few he didn't ask about...

Comment: Five upvotes for this? Hmm.

Answer (score 2):

I find your sentence marginal bordering on unidiomatic.  "when you **were** in Paris" establishes a past time frame, and thus the question should be "Did you ever" not "Have you ever".

> <strike>Have you ever visited the Louvre when you were in Paris?</strike>
>
> Did you ever visit the Louvre when you were in Paris?

"when you *have been* in Paris" can serve as a semantic bridge between present and past:

> I don't believe there's a word of truth in what you *are saying*  about the sunlight on the cathedral. Both times *you've been* in Paris it *was* during a thunderstorm with unrelenting dark cloud.

This would be idiomatic given that bridge:

> I've been to Paris a couple of times on business but couldn't do any sightseeing. I flew in and flew out with nothing but meetings all day. Have you ever visited the Louvre when *you've been* in Paris?

So even though I rejected it above, with "when you were in Paris", standing alone bare naked as it was, wholly without context, striking the sentence out, when placed in an appropriate context it can become idiomatic with a shift of tense in the *when*-clause.

With respect to the past continuous, it isn't as confined to the past as completely as the simple past is; to my ear the following is idiomatic:

> I was out looking for edible mushrooms this morning and found nothing but toadstools. Have you ever found nothing but toadstools when you *were looking* for mushrooms?

So, with questions involving the nuances of tenses, context is king.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, you wouldn't use the first one in any context?

Comment: Have you ever visited the Louvre when you were in Paris? is completely idiomatic. Have you ever eaten rum cakes when you fancied something sweet?

Comment: @MickeyQ:  If, in context, "Have you ever visited the Louvre when you were in Paris?" refers to *multiple* visits to Paris,  such that the question could be paraphased "Did you visit the Louvre on any of your visits to Paris?", then you could mix the tenses in that way.  But  I find that hybrid mix to be not fully idiomatic -- not ungrammatical but not perfectly idiomatic.  Native speakers can have differerent senses of where the deepest channel of the idiomatic river lies.

Comment: @TimR From what I've learned here, _Have you ever visited the Louvre when **you've been** in Paris?_ also refers to _multiple_ visits to Paris and both sentences are idiomatic, as well as the other sentences discussed. So, it's just about a speaker's preference which one to choose. Thanks a lot, everyone!

Comment: @MickeyQ   You have to judge from context.  "When you were a kid", for example, refers to a span of time, a past period in one's life, and so this, to my ear, is not idiomatic: "Have you ever been to a professional baseball game *when you were a kid*?" The idiomatic version of that question is "Did you ever go to a professional baseball game when you were a kid?"

Answer (score 1):

The sample sentences below are completely idiomatic in English:

- Have you **ever** visited the Louvre when you have been in Paris?

is idiomatic but a native speaker would **tend to say** it this way:

- **Have you ever visited** the Louvre when **you've been** in Paris?
- Have you ever seen a yellow butterfly when you were looking for a white one? COMPARE
- Do you ever see yellow butterflys when you are looking for white ones? Both are grammatical.

> British Council
> We also use it [the present perfect] to talk about
> life experiences, as our life is also an unfinished time period. **We
> often use never in negative sentences and ever in questions**.
>
> I've worked for six different companies.
> He's **never** won a gold medal.
> Have you **ever** been to Australia?

[use of the present perfect from the British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/present-perfect#:%7E:text=Again%2C%20if%20we%20say%20when,started%20going%20to%20the%20gym.)

Senator Kaine: I have heard Hillary Clinton say over and over again, when I've been sitting next to her and when I've watched her on TV that, with respect to the e-mails, "I made a mistake and I've learned something and I wouldn't do it again.", and I've heard her apologize.

- all of those are unspecified as to when they occurred. A speaker referring to an unspecified time in the past in relation to the present time of speaking often makes use of the present perfect and present prefect continuous (for an action verb) precisely because it is not a finished or past action with a time adverbial, stated or implied.

The senator claims she said: I made a mistake. That's right grammatically. She made a mistake at a specific moment in the past and this simple past usage **can**, but does not **require**, using a time adverbial such as last week, two years ago etc. It is merely a finished thing in the past.

> **More from that British Council link**:
> Finished time and states
> If we say when something
> happened, or we feel that that part of our life is finished, we use
> the past simple.
>
> We visited Russia for the first time in 1992.
> I went to three
> different primary schools.
> Before she retired, she worked in several
> different countries.

In sum, it is perfectly natural in connected speech (and in writing) to use a simple past and past perfect in a series of utterances or even in a single utterance. In other words, it is fine to mix them up if warranted by the speaker's intention.

- I've just finished answering this question [now]. I've been answering it for the last ten minutes. How did I do?

Are the above statements grammatical in a series? Answer: Yes, they are.

When I **went** to Paris, I **saw** him.

When I **saw** him, I **was riding** my bike.

When I **'ve gone** to Paris, I'**ve seen** him.

When I **was riding** my bike, I **saw** him.

When I'**ve been riding** my bike around town, I **'ve seen** him.

I think I've covered most of them.

[Please note: This is **not** a comprehensive answer for the present prefect.]

Comment: All credits to you @Lambie! What a great answer! Other answers aren't less great too. What is your opinion about the [1] and the  [2]?

Comment: @MickeyQ Whoops, I forgot the continuous one. But I already answered 1).

Comment: @ Lambie I don't see it!

Comment: @MickeyQ You've now changed your question so it's a bit difficult to figure out every single combination.